# A regular expression to extract a business extension from a phone number

Tags: php, regex, phone-number

I am having the dang-est time trying to write a regex that will extract the phone extension from a full phone number string. This should work on a number like this one: 777.777.7777 x 7302

It should also work using "ext", "EXT", "Ext", "eXt", "ext.", and "Ext ". Essentially just cover all the common ground use of it.

I just need the "x 7302" part. In fact I am just going to strip it down to just the extension number once I extract it.

Can anyone help me please? Regular expressions are something that I struggle with when they get more complex.

I am doing this in a PHP function (preg_match) if that will help anyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try with regex:

```
/e?xt?\.?\s*\d+$/i 

<?

echo "<pre>";
     $phone = '777.777.7777 x 7302'; 
        preg_match("/e?xt?\.?\s*\d+$/i", $phone, $matched); 
        print_r($matched);
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => x 7302
)
```

Comment: here again different than hakre's post, how `$matched` gives the matched output from regex?

Comment: I have go to say this one worked for me. I had a big list of possible patterns and put this at the end of the list (even below the other pattern answer listed above) and it was the only one to find it. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This probably helps to give you something to play with:

```
$phonenumber = '777.777.7777 x 7302';

$extension = preg_replace('(^.*(ext|x) ?([0-9]+)$)i', '$2', $phonenumber);

echo $extension;
```

Use the `i` modifier (at the end) to make the regex case insensitive so to match all combinations of `ext`. I used a group to offer both variant: `ext` or `x`: `(ext|x)`.

The rest is looking for a number at the end, and a space is possible between EXT and the number.

Comment: how `$2` will give me `7302`, can you please explain that?

Comment: @user: `$2` contains the match of the second group: `([0-9]+)`

Comment: +1 for explicitly mentioning the `i` modifier and explaining it. I think @The Mask's regex is probably better, though

Comment: I like it. I appreciate the help. I voted you up for the great answer, but I have to go with the one below since it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
\w+\s*\d+$
```

It is an simpler regex assuming that the input is similar to what you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you

```
/([\d\-\.]+)([ext\. ]+)(\d+)/i
```

The first set matches the numbers separated by dash or dot. The second set matches your extension string and the third set matches your extension number.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the last numbers of the string, you can use:

```
\D+(\d+)$
```

`\D+` at least one non-digit followed by:

`(\d+)` at least one digit (captured using parenthesis)

`$` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
$pn = "777.777.7777 x 7302"; 

function get_ext($pn)
{
$ext = preg_replace('/[\d\.\s]+[ext\s]+(\d{1,})/i', '$1', $pn);
return $ext;
}

echo get_ext($pn);
//7302
```

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit leery of regular expression, so I'm a bit biased when I say, is it possible to just split the string using the PHP function "explode()", using the 'x' character as your delimiter?

Here is a link to the PHP manual for that function if you are not familiar with it:

[Explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)